# how many threads are created by multiple coroutines in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I created a simple program where I launched 3 coroutines using GlobalScope.launch
which all print 100 lines of code of it's progress, coroutine 1 calls a suspend function when half of it's execution completed.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

fun main(){
    println("Actual Program starts here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

    GlobalScope.launch {
        println("C1 starts here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        for(i in 1..100){
            if(i == 50){
                mfunction()
            }
            println("C1 progress  = $i : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
        println("C1 Ends here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    GlobalScope.launch {
        println("C2 starts here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        for(i in 1..100){
            println("C2 progress  = $i : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
        println("C2 Ends here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    GlobalScope.launch {
        println("C3 starts here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        for(i in 1..100){
            println("C3 progress  = $i : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
        println("C3 Ends here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    for(i in 1..100){
        println("Actual Work progress  = $i : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    println("Actual Program Ends here : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
}

suspend fun mfunction(){
    for(i in 1..100){
        println("Suspend Work progress  = $i : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
}
```

As main thread is there by default. My Question is , will each coroutine create a new thread(**for it's execution**) to be run on or they all will run on a single background thread??

I executed this program,
I get DefaultDispatcher-worker1 for Coroutine1, and DefaultDispatcher-worker2 for Coroutine2 and DefaultDispatcher-worker3 for Coroutine3 But sometimes i get DefaultDispatcher-worker1 for all coroutines.

I am not able to figure out the behaviour what is happening internally.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Number of threads depends on which dispatcher was used and what your code does. Maximum number of threads that `Dispatchers.Default` (which you use here) can create is equal to the number of physical cores you have. If you would create e.g. 5 coroutines on 4-cores CPU then fifth coroutine would start after one of them would finish.

However, above is true only because your code is CPU-intensive and it doesn't at all suspend. If you would wait not with a busy loop, but through `delay()` then you could run even thousands of coroutines on a single thread.

Coroutines can also switch from one thread to another. You can start a coroutine in some thread and after a suspension point it could continue in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

> will each coroutine create a new thread

Coroutines doesn't create threads. They use existing threads of some [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html), which `CoroutineDispatcher` you run your couroutines on ([Dispatchers.Default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) in your case) points to. Submitted tasks distribution on threads depends on internal implementation of respectful thread pool.